# Collapse no Boostrap 4 não está abrindo

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

```css
body {
      font: 400 20px Times New Roman, Arial, Arial Nova Light, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #818181;
}

h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
}  
.jumbotron {
      background-color: #4f0000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 100px 25px;
      font-family: Times New Roman, sans-serif;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.bg-grey {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.logo-image{
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.logo-brand{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    width: 50px;
    color: #164b64;
}
.logo-small {
      color:#164b64;
      font-size: 50px;
}
.logo {
      color: #164b64;
      font-size: 200px;
}
.navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #004f4f;/* 3d3d6c*/
      z-index: 9999;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      /*line-height: 1.42857143 !important;*/
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #fff !important;
      background-color: #164b64 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  } 
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2000px){
  .slidean{font-size: 190px}
  .slideanim{font-size: 190px}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px){
  .slidean{font-size: 130px;}
  .slideanim{font-size: 120px;}
  .logo-smal{font-size: 60px}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  .slidean{ font-size: 100px }
  .slideanim{ font-size: 100px }
  .col-sm-4 {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .slidean{display: none;}
  .logo {font-size: 150px;}  
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Definindo informações do site para crawlers--->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--Icons-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <!--Boostrap 4-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Estilo personalizado-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
  <script src="js/scripty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#myPage">
        <img class="logo-brand" src="./images/logo.png"> Lorem Ipsum
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class=" fas fa-ellipsis-v" style="color:#282828"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#formation">FORMATION</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#portifolio">PORTIFOLIO</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#courses">COURSES</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#acquaintance">ACQUAINTANCE</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#citations">CITATIONS</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é simples, vc esqueceu de adicionar o jQuery no `<head>` Ele deve vir antes do `popper.js` e antes do `bootstrap.js`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está um Template base indicado pela própria documentação oficial do Bootstrap. Repare que além do jQuery, eles também indicam que todos os `.js` devem vir ao final do documento, e a ordem seria `jquery/popper/bootstrap` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/?#starter-template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>



  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Definindo informações do site para crawlers--->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!--Icons-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <!--Boostrap 4-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Estilo personalizado-->



<style>
  body {
      font: 400 20px Times New Roman, Arial, Arial Nova Light, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #818181;
}

h4 {
      font-size: 19px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #303030;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
}  
.jumbotron {
      background-color: #4f0000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 100px 25px;
      font-family: Times New Roman, sans-serif;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.bg-grey {
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.logo-image{
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.logo-brand{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    width: 50px;
    color: #164b64;
}
.logo-small {
      color:#164b64;
      font-size: 50px;
}
.logo {
      color: #164b64;
      font-size: 200px;
}
.navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #004f4f;/* 3d3d6c*/
      z-index: 9999;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 12px !important;
      /*line-height: 1.42857143 !important;*/
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #fff !important;
      background-color: #164b64 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  } 
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2000px){
  .slidean{font-size: 190px}
  .slideanim{font-size: 190px}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px){
  .slidean{font-size: 130px;}
  .slideanim{font-size: 120px;}
  .logo-smal{font-size: 60px}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  .slidean{ font-size: 100px }
  .slideanim{ font-size: 100px }
  .col-sm-4 {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .slidean{display: none;}
  .logo {font-size: 150px;}  
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#myPage">
          <img class="logo-brand" src="./images/logo.png"> Lorem Ipsum
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class=" fas fa-ellipsis-v" style="color:#282828"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#formation">FORMATION</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#portifolio">PORTIFOLIO</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#courses">COURSES</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#acquaintance">ACQUAINTANCE</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#citations">CITATIONS</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
              <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  
  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body> -->
</html>
```